# how can i check the value of a variable from a controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I am doing an upload image file in CodeIgniter. I want to trace out the image in my code and update my database path with it. I want to print the `$image_path` variable in the code below where it was located in my controller.

How can I print the `$image_path` variable to display or check its value inside the controller or maybe echo it out  ?

Here it is:

```
<?php
public function upload_file()
{
        $status = "";
        $msg = "";
        $file_element_name = 'userfile';

        if ($status != "error") {
                $config['upload_path'] = './assets/upimages/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
                $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file_element_name))
                {
                        $status = 'error';
                        $msg = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
                }
                else
                {
                        $data = $this->upload->data();
                        $image_path = $data['full_path'];
                        if(file_exists($image_path))
                        {
                                $status = "success";
                                $msg = "File successfully uploaded";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                $status = "error";
                                $msg = "Something went wrong when saving the file, please try again.";
                        }
                }
                @unlink($_FILES[$file_element_name]);
        }
        echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for editting sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question your asking then you want to view the contents of the `$image_path` variable.

If all you want is to check this then you could pass it back to the view with the json array `('image_path' => $image_path)`.

The other option is to `var_dump($image_path)` however to view this you would need to inspect the post data response on the browser and it may also stop the json from working while you are using the `var_dump()`.

Blinky

Comment: where can i see the value when i used var_dump?

Comment: On Firefox (this is what I am using) open the inspect element, right click.  Then go to the network or console tab and click on the upload submission button on your view.  Then you should see the post request being sent.  Click on that and inspect it, in there you should find the response that will include the var_dump.  For testing it may be easier to use the json array and console.log the response in the view, this will in turn be displayed into the browsers console.

Answer (score 0):

try `echo $image_path;` or `print_r($image_path)`